# Accessing individual array elements using jQuery each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to find the answer for this but how can you access an individual array element by it's index number in jQuery's each method?

Stright JS would do it like this:

```
for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(i === 1)
    {    
        // do something
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to use find the index number in the each method...?

```
myArray.each(function()
{
    if(this[1])
    {
        // doesn't work?
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do:

```
$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

And more importantly, see: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  Sorry for such a simple question, but I've been working all night on some code and my brain is fried.

Comment: @Freethinker no prob... happens at times.. :)